# Why ignoreAcceptHeader method of ContentNegotiatingViewResolver is removed after Spring 4.2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We are just updating our spring framework from 4.1.1 to 4.2.5. Interesting thing is that, we just find the **ignoreAcceptHeader** method is removed from ContentNegotiatingViewResolver. Any idea about that? How can we set ignoreAcceptHeader property after 4.2.x?

Following is our old code

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">

    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json; charset=UTF-8" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <ref bean="viewResolver" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: By using the `ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean` to configure `ContentNegotiationManager` which needs to be injected into the `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. Which is also explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-content-negotiation) in the part explaining the differences between 4.1 and 4.2.

Comment: Thanks for your information. It is helpful for the project. :)